# Angular wizard with component as contents of each steps

Tags: angular, wizard, stepper

Is there any angular wizards or stepper exists which provides the option to load the angular components as steps body

```
longsteps-component-start 
step1-component 
step2-component
step3-component 
step-final-component
```

Not wanted to add all logic inside the same ts file.Instead i would like to keep the component specific logic inside the corresponding ts files and share data between components with help of services.

Also i am not using Angular Material Library inside my project , so `mat-step`  will not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in a childrouting for the special page?
I hope the answer helps you?

Comment: Does using routing instead of wizard steps a good practise?

Comment: I would argue that this is the case.
After all, the routing offers you nothing but that.
It dynamically exchanges pages and you can say in each component how where and when it should jump where.
Moreover, the steps can be easily implemented via a navigation with Routerlink and RouterLinkActive